# How do i Integrate decryption function in node.js which is encrypted by php function

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption

Here is my php code for which i'm using for encryption and decryption.This method is working on node.js also by using exec-php node modules but now i want to make a similar function in node and i'm using crypto node module for this but i'm unable to decrypt data properly.

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'Key for encryption and decryption';
    $secret_iv = 'IV for openssl';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Always using the same IV ? ==> not secure.
You really need the iv to be random and have a way of sharing/agreeing on it before you start to use AES.  Developing crypto software is not for the novice, even experts can make terrible mistakes. Please use a library that has been peer reviewed that does it for you instead of developing stuff like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. Try it yourself and if you're not successful, show the two code parts, example inputs and outputs.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Common practice to use a random IV and then prepend it to the encrypted data, the IV does not need to be secret.

Comment: Did it using exec-php to run php function from node